# Python tkinker resitze Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollview, tkinter-canvas

I have an Python3 Tkinter Programm. I have 3 Frames in the Main Window and in one Frame an canvas with scroll Option - now i want resitze the Canvas Area .
Now if i resize it moves the Scroll Bar for Y out the Window and the scrollbar for x works also not as expected (get bigger but slide area don't change)
How i Mange it to resize an Canvas in an grid Layout - The Window must be the same size , the Scrollbas must be updatet and the Canvas Plane must be bigger.
an excerpt from my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def menu_build():
    caninfo[0] += 10
    cangui.configure(width = caninfo[0])
    #cangui.configure(scrollregion=cangui.bbox("all"))

def gui():
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.title( "Easy Switch" )
    master.geometry("480x320")
    frametop = tk.Frame(master, bg="blue", bd=2)
    frametop.grid(column=0,row=0)
    frameex = tk.Frame(master, bg="yellow", bd=2)
    frameex.grid(column=1,row=1)
    framegui = tk.Frame(master, bg="red", bd=2)
    framegui.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=1)
    
    menu = tk.Menu(master)
    master.config(menu=menu)
    filemenu = tk.Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Config", menu=filemenu)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Resize",command=menu_build)
    global cangui
    cangui = tk.Canvas(framegui, width=385, height=250)
    #caninfo = [385,250]
    cangui.grid(row=1, column=2)
    scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(framegui, orient="horizontal", command=cangui.xview)
    scroll_x.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="ew")
    scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(framegui, orient="vertical", command=cangui.yview)
    scroll_y.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="ns")
    cangui.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set,xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)
    cangui.configure(scrollregion=cangui.bbox("all"))
    cwcb = tk.Checkbutton(framegui,  text="ccw").grid(row=2,column=0)
    
    cangui.create_arc(90,90,110,110,style=tk.PIESLICE,width=4,start=0,extent=300)
    master.mainloop() 
    
global caninfo
caninfo = [385,250]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to resize the canvas Area

wrote an extra funktion

`win = [int(cangui.cget("width")),int(cangui.cget("height"))]
    draw_xy = cangui.bbox("all")
    swin = (min(0,draw_xy[0]),min(0,draw_xy[1]),max(draw_xy[2],win[0]),max(draw_xy[3],win[1]))
    cangui.configure(scrollregion=swin)`

reason: canvas.bbox("all") gives only the positon from most upper/left grafic and i want 0/0